# Show animated gif while redirecting to other page

Tags: jquery, ios, loader, animated-gif

I want to show a loading GIF while I redirect user to another page, so I just do jquery's .show() to show the div that contains the loading GIF image as soon as the user clicks on a link. This works perfectly fine in all browsers/devices except on iPhone and iPad. On those devices, the animated GIF images does not play and displays just the first frame. The GIF image plays fine if I just display it on the page. Apparently, iPad and iPhones stop playing the GIF image during redirection. How can I get around this behavior?